# Can a cursor do a select join query?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor

I want to write a cursor that holds a join query so that I would be able to print
values from the columns of two separate tables. How do I do that?

Here is my failed attempt at it.

```
DECLARE
CURSOR curs is select C_SEC_ID, COURSE_NO from COURSE_SECTION
JOIN COURSE ON COURSE_SECTION.COURSE_NO = COURSE.COURSE_NO
WHERE COURSE_NO LIKE '%MIS%';
BEGIN
NULL;
END;
```

Comment: Cursor can hold and query which you can write and execute without cursor. Which fail you got when attempt?

Comment: Always in situations like this, run the query by itself (forget about "cursor") and see if the query goes through. If it doesn't, you will know the query is wrong, and your errors have nothing to do with "cursor".

Answer (score 1):

`dbms_output.put_line` may be used :

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> DECLARE
CURSOR curs is 
  SELECT s.C_SEC_ID, c.COURSE_NO 
    FROM COURSE_SECTION s JOIN COURSE c ON ( s.COURSE_NO = c.COURSE_NO )
   WHERE s.COURSE_NO LIKE '%MIS%';
BEGIN
   for c in curs
   loop
     dbms_output.put_line(c.C_SEC_ID||'  '||c.COURSE_NO);
   end loop;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You got failed because you are not using any aliases for column "COURSE_NO", and this column falls in both of table in your scenario.

Try below PL/SQL block.

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR curs is 
    select C_SEC_ID, COURSE_SECTION.COURSE_NO
      from COURSE_SECTION
      JOIN COURSE
        ON COURSE_SECTION.COURSE_NO = COURSE.COURSE_NO
  WHERE COURSE_SECTION.COURSE_NO LIKE '%MIS%';
BEGIN
NULL;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you. I see.